# Linux processes - Too large for RAM usage. What is it?

Tags: process, memory, top

This is what I see in my Linux Debian Server:

[image]
[image]

The values "Size" (1. image) or "VIRT" (2. image) are too big for "RAM usage". What are they?

Comment: What do you mean by "too big for RAM usage"?

Comment: @Kusalananda It is like 50GB total. My memory is only 4Gigs